# Applying static methods to data stored in a subclass

Tags: java

I'm working on a class to access information about a class library stored in a Jar file and run actions customized for each class library. It contains methods to load localized strings, etc. from the Jar file.

```
public class CodeBundle {
    public static String str(String id) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

I need to be able to know which library I am trying to load information from, so I want to be able to use subclasses representing each library, for example:

```
public class JAppFramework extends CodeBundle {
    ...
}
```

So now in code that is part of the JApp Framework, I want to be able to call `JAppFramework.str("...")` to load a string from the JApp Framework resource bundle. And if I have another library, such as `TestLibrary`, I want to be able to call `TestLibrary.str("...")` to load a string from Test Library's resource bundle. What I did was have a method defined in `CodeBundle` called `getFile()` which would return the Jar file from which the library had been loaded. Then the `str()` method would use that to load the localized string.

The problem is that the static methods in `CodeBundle` can only access data stored in the `CodeBundle` class, not in any of its subclasses, as far as I know.

For various reasons, I can't use "getClass().getResource(name)" to load resources.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try and use singletons:

```
public abstract class CodeBundle { // or even an interface
    public abstract String str(String id);
}

public final class JAppFramework extends CodeBundle {
    private static final CodeBundle INSTANCE = new JAppFramework();

    // private constructor
    private JAppFramework() {
        // whatever
    }

    // get the instance
    public static CodeBundle getInstance() { return INSTANCE; }

    // Implement str() here
}

// Create other singletons as needed
```

In your code:

```
CodeBundle bundle = JAppFramework.getInstance();
bundle.str(whatever);
```

Of course, this is an ultra simplistic example. Put whatever fields/methods/constructors/constructor arguments are needed in `CodeBundle` -- which cannot be instantiated since it is abstract.